# Difference in XRM.Page API calls when saving hidden field

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015, xrm

I have a function in JS which is triggered as event handler when user picks new option from dropdown.

```
function providerMarketingListOnChangeEventHandler() {
    console.log("Provider marketing list option changed!");
    // Get selected provider m. list option value
    var selectedMarketingListValue = $(this).find("option:selected").text();

    // Use XRM.Page API to set hidden attribute value to the value of the selected option
    // Option 1 - this?   
    // Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_marketinglist_provider").setValue(selectedMarketingListValue);

    // Option 2 - or this?     
    // Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_marketinglist_provider").setValue(selectedMarketingListValue);
    Xrm.Page.data.entity.save();
}
```

Dropdown is loaded as WebResource on **CRM 2015** form. The entity for this form has field named "**new_marketinglist_provider**", but it **has to be hidden** on the form.

Now I am trying to save selected option text to this field, and save entity. I have two `Xrm.Page` API calls, but which one should I use? (Please see comments in function.)

Comment: None of these work if the field is not on the form. I had to add field to the form, and set default visibility to "invisible" on form properties. After this, attribute is available for use in JS like:
Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_marketinglist_provider")...

Comment: getAttribute is just a shortcut for data.entity.attributes.get

Answer (score 0):

try this :

Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_marketinglist_provider").setValue(selectedMarketingListValue);

Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_marketinglist_provider").setSubmitMode("always");